# Fill predefined pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a predefined dataframe `df1`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", "col_a","col_b","col_c"])
```

I have a json file:

```
{'123': {'col_a': 5, 'col_b': "kuku", 'col_c': True}}
```

Or sometimes it can be:

```
{'123': {'col_a': 5, 'col_b': ["kuku", "bubu", "fooo"], 'col_c': True}}
```

Where `'123'` key is the `id`.

I want to add these json's data to my dataframe as new line/lines but if col_b is a list, I want it to be:

```
id    col_a col_b col_c
123   5     kuku  True
123   5     bubu  True
123   5     fooo  True
```

Or apply one hot encoder to `col_b`.

I am using `pd.json_normalize` but I want to also unnest the list and add the id value.

Please advise what is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Do you want multiple indexes in your dataframe? Otherwise you would have to make a separe column for each possible position in that list.

Comment: @srcolinas I need the 123 id to be for each element of the list.
If I have 1000 elements in the list (and I have 3 list columns like this) there will be 1000 rows with id 123 + col_a value (which will be the same for all 1000 rows and same for col_c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the cleanest, but you can do:

```
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame(new_json).T
                   .explode('col_b')
                   .rename_axis('id')
                   .reset_index()
                )
```

Output:

```
    id col_a col_b col_c
0  123     5  kuku  True
1  123     5  bubu  True
2  123     5  fooo  True
```

Comment: What is T here?

Comment: @SteveS That's Transpose

Comment: We need first to parse it, no? That's why I am using `pd.json_normalize`

Comment: @anky apparently `new_json` is a dictionary from the json string. So you are correct. Thanks

Comment: Print the dataframe without transpose and you see why. Basically we want the transpose of `pd.DataFrame` output.